# Android: won't play rtp stream

Tags: android, media, rtp, jmf

I want to make an app which plays the sound from an server.
Receiving and playing from the internet works, but with my JMF-Programm it does not work (Error (-38,0)).

here is my code-snippet from the app:

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    // String url
    // ="http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hosannatelugu.mp3";
    String url = "rtp://192.168.32.29:22222/audio/16";
    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volume, volume);

    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        mPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    mPlayer.start();
```

when I use "http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hosannatelugu.mp3" it works, but "rtp://192.168.32.29:22222/audio/16" sends me error (-38,0)

Can someone help me?
Thanks